# Can't log into WSO2 Carbon behind load balancer

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2IS 5.0.0 instance running on a VM behind a load balancer. The load balancer listens for HTTPS on port 443, handles all SSL and forwards plain HTTP to the VM on port 80.

I have configured the WSO2IS instance to have only one HTTP connector on port 80 in catalina-server.xml, and configured all the URLs I can find in the config to point to the load balancer using HTTPS.

I can visit the carbon webapp via the load balancer on 443 fine. However when I successfully log in, the webapp returns a redirect to HTTP on port 80, NOT to HTTPS on port 443 as it should. This makes it impossible to use the carbon webapp.

If I change proxyPort in the HTTP connector in catalina-server.xml, it does then return a redirect to port 443 - but the URL is plain HTTP, not HTTPS, so it still fails.

How can I tell carbon to send a redirect to HTTPS even though tomcat itself is listening via HTTP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use proxy port in this scenario.

You can configure in tomcat/catalina-server.xml as below with 2 connectors. http url will anyway redirect to https url. Do you mean management console as webapp?

```
 <Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="9763"
                proxyPort="80"
                bindOnInit="false"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                acceptorThreadCount="2"
                maxThreads="250"
                minSpareThreads="50"
                disableUploadTimeout="false"
                connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
                maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
                acceptCount="200"
                server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
                compression="on"
                compressionMinSize="2048"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg" 
                URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

    <Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="9443"
                proxyPort="443"
                bindOnInit="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                acceptorThreadCount="2"
                maxThreads="250"
                minSpareThreads="50"
                disableUploadTimeout="false"
                enableLookups="false"
                connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
                maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
                acceptCount="200"
                server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
                clientAuth="false"
                compression="on"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                compressionMinSize="2048"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
                URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

You should have the mapping to your load balancer in your etc/hosts file as :

is.50.com

In Your Load balancer you should have as below. E.g., apache2

```
<Virtualhost *:443>
        ServerName is.50.com
        ServerAlias is.50.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

 <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
 </Proxy>

stickysession=JSESSIONID


ProxyPass / https://<carbonIP>:<port>/
ProxyPassReverse / https://<carbonIP>:<port>/

</Virtualhost>
```

Then your access URL will be, as below.

https://is.50.com/carbon

or

http://is.50.com/carbon which will redirect to https.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Ushani! Yes I meant the management console webapp.

Your example is connecting from the load balancer to the server by HTTPS. I want to use plain HTTP from the load balancer to the server, and just serve HTTPS from the load balancer to the public, to save running unnecessary crypto on the server, which will be seeing a lot of traffic. Do you know a way this can be done?

Comment: By configuring HTTPs in catalina-server.xml only it will allocate 9443 port. Therefore you cannot avoid having https port.

Comment: You can also try out another option by enabling below property in carbon.xml. By this it wil enable you to use the admin console with http. But redirecting to https won't work unless you enable it in catalina-server.xml. You can follow this blogpost [1].

<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole> 

[1] http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-enable-wso2-carbon-management.html

Comment: Yes this worked! I found I also had to enable '<HttpAdminServices>*</HttpAdminServices>' in carbon.xml, and set proxyPort="443" and scheme="https" in the connector config in catalina-server.xml.

Thank you!